# What does compiling or decompiling an MS Access MDB file do?

Tags: ms-access, compilation, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a legacy Access application. The other day it was crashing, and crashed during Compact and Repair. After a whole bunch of Googling, what I finally had to do was decompile the MDB, then recompile it, and it would run again.

So my question is, what does Decompiling an MDB do, or for that matter what does compiling an MDB do? The code is accessible to me either way, and it appears the same in the VBA code editor. So is it just something internal to MS Access MDBs?

Comment: Compiling creates "p-code" from your code text.  The VBA host runs the p-code not the text.  The p-code is stored in a system table BLOB.  When that stored binary information gets corrupted, weird stuff happens.  Decompiling discards all the stored p-code, corrupted or not.  Then when you compile again, the new clean p-code is stored ... and hopefully life is good again.  Experienced Access developers often recommend decompile on a regular basis during active development as a prophylactic measure.

Comment: Decompile is not 100% successful.  You can use the undocumented `Application.SaveAsText` method to save your code-bearing objects (modules, classes, forms, reports) to text files.  When decompile fails to restore order, use `Application.LoadFromText` in a new db file.

Comment: Thank you. That was brilliantly helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA gets compiled to `intermediate language` (if I remember correctly it's called `P-code`). You don't see it. It's embedded into the file.

When you save MS-Access database as .mde or .accde only the compiled version exists in the file. There is no code you can see.

**AFAIK:**

There are few states to your code. Your clean text code, which gets automatically compiled to let's call it `op-code` which gets compiled to `Packed code`. And when it runs it uses VM JIT to compile it on fly to machine code.

When your code gets compiled and you make changes to your source code you loose the compiled state when you run the application and then it runs in `debug` mode of the auto-compiled op-codes until you compile it again.